# WSO2 API Manager net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have configured WSO2 API Manager and WSO2 Identity Server togother.I have then configured my custom domain in carbon.xml . Its working fine and I can access in Publisher/Portal.I have CA signed certificates installed in WSO2 as well.

But now when i invoked API's via store , I am getting an insecure response and it happens because it points to the earlier IP's . The call is going to 
OPTIONS https://11.111.210.80:8244/api/v1/api net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

ideally it should go to my custom domain itself.

How can i fix this?

I can see this IP mentioned in the api-manager.xml at many places.Should i change all of them with my custom domain name?
Or should i do any other changes?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update URLs in `<GatewayEndpoint>` in `<APIGateway>` section with the hostnames.

Comment: I did it..
Now i am getting a different error

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://mywso.mydomain.us:8244/api/v1/myapis. Redirect from 'http  :9444/store/apis/info?name=mydomain&version=v1&provider=admin#!/default/get_myapis:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://mywso.mydomain.us:8244/api/v1/myapis. Redirect from 'https://mywso.mydomain.us:8244/api/v1/myapis' to 'https://mywso.mydomain.us:9444/usrbon/admin/login.jsp' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect.

Comment: what is your browser? If it's IE, can you try with some other browser as well?

Comment: i am using chrome

Comment: Are you trying in API Console of Store?

Comment: Yes..API console of Store..
I just tried hit the URL directly via postMan..it gives me 200 ok ;but the response is an HTML which shows the login page for the WSO

Comment: That's the problem. Something's wrong with your API. It redirects to the login page for some reason. That's why it gives a CORS error. You have to fix your API first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136090/discussion-between-jocket-and-bhathiya).

Comment: My API itself is fine..I have problem invoking via Store..
I tried to invoke the wso2 API URL via post master and then i got the login page
My API gives me proper response ..
Where can i see the logs?

Comment: I think you are correct.I had problems with API. It works now.Thanks for your support.